# Adding multiple records through rails API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I have an `Availability` model, I want to send an API post request to create multiple availabilities at once.

I stumbled on this [post on medium](https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-build-html-inputs-to-submit-an-array-of-hashes-with-a-rails-form-tag-that-work-with-strong-f70a6c03d78e) and I was so excited that it will fix my problem but it didn't, because the author is using a Rails form template while I'm sending my request through the API.

I researched further into the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) found a way to create multiple records, tried the approach there as well but did not work for me.

Here's my controller code. The `create` method and the `availability_params` method.

```
module API
  module V1
    class AvailabilitiesController < ApiController
      def create
        availability = Availability.new(availability_params)
        availability.tutor = current_user

        availability.start_time = DateTime.parse("#{availability_params[:day_of_the_week]} #{availability_params[:start_time]}")
        availability.end_time = DateTime.parse("#{availability_params[:day_of_the_week]} #{availability_params[:end_time]}")

        if availability.start_time < DateTime.current && availability.end_time < DateTime.current
          availability.start_time += 1.week
          availability.end_time += 1.week
        end

        if availability.save
          render json: {
            availability: availability,
            message: 'Your availability was created successfully.'
          }
        else
          render json: { message: 'There was a problem creating your availability.', errors: availability.errors }, status: :bad_request
        end
      end

      def destroy
        Availability.where(id: params[:ids]).destroy_all
      end


      def availability_params
        params.require(:availability).permit(:day_of_the_week, :start_time, :end_time).tap do |availability_params|
          availability_params.require([:day_of_the_week, :start_time, :end_time])
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

And the request from the front end using axios looks like this:

`axios.post('/api/v1/availabilities', { availability: payload })`

The destroy function also sends this type of request:

`axios.delete('/api/v1/availabilities', { params: { ids: payload } })`

A sample output of that request, when sent looks like this:

```
web_1        | Started POST "/api/v1/availabilities" for 172.18.0.1 at 2018-10-29 18:07:27 +0000
web_1        | Cannot render console from 172.18.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
web_1        | Processing by API::V1::AvailabilitiesController#create as JSON
web_1        |   Parameters: {"availability"=>[{"start_time"=>"2018-10-30T13:00:00.000Z", "end_time"=>"2018-10-30T13:30:00.000Z", "day_of_the_week"=>"Tuesday", "tutor_id"=>1}, {"start_time"=>"2018-10-30T13:30:00.000Z", "end_time"=>"2018-10-30T14:00:00.000Z", "day_of_the_week"=>"Tuesday", "tutor_id"=>1}, {"start_time"=>"2018-10-30T14:00:00.000Z", "end_time"=>"2018-10-30T14:30:00.000Z", "day_of_the_week"=>"Tuesday", "tutor_id"=>1}, {"start_time"=>"2018-10-30T14:30:00.000Z", "end_time"=>"2018-10-30T15:00:00.000Z", "day_of_the_week"=>"Tuesday", "tutor_id"=>1}, {"start_time"=>"2018-10-30T15:00:00.000Z", "end_time"=>"2018-10-30T15:30:00.000Z", "day_of_the_week"=>"Tuesday", "tutor_id"=>1}]}
web_1        |   User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY id LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
web_1        |   ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:114
web_1        | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 35ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
web_1        | 
web_1        | 
web_1        |   
web_1        | NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for #<Array:0x00007f1f26d889d8>):
```

What exactly I'm I doing wrong? Any suggestions will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. If you look at the log, you can see params[:availability] is an array, but your `create` method is handling it as a simple hash of attribs representing one item.

Do  a loop like:

```
 def create
    params[:availability].each { |availability_params|
     availability = Availability.find_or_create_by(availability_params[:id]).update_attributes(availability_params]
  }
  # etc
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, but that didn't work. Here's what my method looks like now. Began creating and then ROLLBACK. with this error -  `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):`

Comment: My example is very simplified, e.g. I didn't show anything about using `permit`, which is the cause of the error here. The main point is you need to loop over the array from params and handle it however makes sense for your problem.

Comment: You are right, I was able to get it to work by doing this - `availability = Availability.new(availability_params.permit(:day_of_the_week, :start_time, :end_time, :tutor_id))` Thank you very much.